# What does the XML syntax with a colon mean?

Tags: xml, xsd, rdl

What does:

```
<rd:...>  </rd:.....>
```

in XML format of RDL file mean and the purpose of it?
Anyone please explain it to me. I just started learning this.

Comment: `:` introduces a namespace prefix.

Comment: Why do we have to use in our xml format, especially in report definition file(RDL) ? Why not just use objects. example...<style>   </style>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The XML syntax, `rd:`, is a namespace prefix, an abbreviation for a namespace URI.

### XML Namespaces

The purpose of XML namespaces is explained clearly in [Section 1, Motivation and Summary](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-intro) of the [W3C Recommendation: Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/):

> We envision applications of Extensible Markup Language (XML) where a
>   single XML document may contain elements and attributes (here referred
>   to as a "markup vocabulary") that are defined for and used by multiple
>   software modules. One motivation for this is modularity: if such a
>   markup vocabulary exists which is well-understood and for which there
>   is useful software available, it is better to re-use this markup
>   rather than re-invent it.
>
> Such documents, containing multiple markup vocabularies, pose problems
>   of recognition and collision. Software modules need to be able to
>   recognize the elements and attributes which they are designed to
>   process, even in the face of "collisions" occurring when markup
>   intended for some other software package uses the same element name or
>   attribute name.
>
> These considerations require that document constructs should have
>   names constructed so as to avoid clashes between names from different
>   markup vocabularies. This specification describes a mechanism, *XML
>   namespaces*, which accomplishes this by assigning [expanded names](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-expname)
>   to elements and attributes.

So, in RDL as with in other standards efforts, namespaces allow the creation of a vocabulary without worry of naming collisions with other vocabularies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.