# Is it possible to have multiple namespace prefixes in XML?

Tags: xml, html, xml-namespaces

I would like to do something like this:

```
<root:secondlevel:thirdlevel
    xmlns:secondlevel="http://secondlevel.com"
    xmlns:secondlevel:thirdlevel="http://thirdlevel.com">
</root:secondlevel:thirdlevel>
```

Is there a way to do those multiple levels `root:secondlevel:thirdlevel` as valid XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, there can be at most one namespace prefix in XML.**

The [XML Namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) BNF rules for names are based on [QName](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-QName), which allows only a single `PrefixedName`:

> ```
> QName          ::= PrefixedName | UnprefixedName
> PrefixedName   ::= Prefix ':' LocalPart
> UnprefixedName ::= LocalPart
> Prefix         ::= NCName
> LocalPart      ::= NCName
> NCName         ::= Name - (Char* ':' Char*) /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */
> ```

Neither `Prefix` nor `LocalPart` allow colon (`:`) characters, so there can be at most one colon (and at most one `Prefix`) part to a `QName`.

**[Side note](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags):** multiple colons are syntactically allowed in base level XML:

> ```
> STag          ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> ```

But the [W3C XML Recommendation is clear](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-common-syn) that colons should not be used except for namespaces purposes:

> **Note:**
>
> The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [[XML Names]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#xml-names) assigns a
>   meaning to names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors
>   should not use the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes,
>   but XML processors must accept the colon as a name character.

And Namespaces do not allow multiple namespace prefixes as shown above.

**See also:**

- [What does the XML syntax with a colon mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325104/what-does-the-xml-syntax-with-a-colon-mean)
- [Is a colon a legal first character in an XML tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445735/is-a-colon-a-legal-first-character-in-an-xml-tag-name/40446164#40446164)

Comment: Does that mean `<my::xml::node>` is valid?

Comment: Multiple colons in an element name would technically be ***well-formed*** (at the base XML level) but not ***namespace-well-formed***.  (Validity is a schema-level concept; see [Well-formed vs Valid XML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) for more details, including more on being namespace-well-formed.)  You won't likely find an XML parser that would ignore ***namespace-well-formed*** violations.   In short: Multiple namespace prefixes: Don't.