# Is it acceptable to use multiple namespace delimiters in JSON/XML properties?

Tags: json, xml, properties, namespaces, naming-conventions

In XML and JSON we may have namespaces in property/element names like so:

```
<system:example>test</system:example>
```

or

```
{ "system:example" : test }
```

In general, does it violate some rules or conventions to have "multi-nested" namespaces like the following?

```
<myapp:sys:authorization>...</myapp:sys:authorization>
```

or

```
 { "myapp:sys:authorization" : { ... } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two questions here...

### JSON

Base [JSON](http://www.json.org/) allows multiple colons in string,

[image]

and makes no reference to namespaces.

### XML

There cannot be multiple namespace prefixes in namespace-well-formed XML. The base XML recommendation allows multiple colons in a tag name but specifically says that colons should be used for namespace prefixes per the XML Namespaces recommendation, which does not allow multiple namespace prefixes in a tag name.  See [Is it possible to have multiple namespace prefixes in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553920/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-namespace-prefixes-in-xml) for details.

### Interoperability

If you're looking for maximal interoperability between JSON and XML, **do not use multiple namespace prefixes.**