# Replace ":" in tags

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have string:

```
<x:tagname x:attribute="value">test content with : symbols</x:tagname>
```

I need result:

```
<x--tagname x--attribute="value">test content with : symbols</x--tagname>
```

how to replace ":" in tags in python?

Comment: If you [**understand what the XML syntax with a colon means**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38325104/290085), then you wouldn't be trying to replace `:` in XML tag names.  See also [**How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085).

Comment: I'm voting to **close this question as off-topic** because it suffers from the [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and asks for a senseless hack instead of a real solution to the actual problem.

Comment: My task - not work with xml. I need to process the text containing xml, and pass it on. If you can not help, then do not close the question. I will find a solution and publish it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the python syntax, but you can use the following regular expression:

```
(?:<|\G)[^>:]*\K:
```

This matches all ':'s inside of tags. Then just replace all occurrences with "--".

### How this works

'\G' matches at the start point of the current round of matching. So by asserting that or matching '<', we can be sure we're inside a tag. Then we just need to look for the next ':' ensuring that we don't encounter a closing '>' while doing so. '\K' effectively dumps the portion of the subject that was just consumed, so it isn't included as part of the substitution.

Comment: 1) This doesn't fit the requirements. 2) backtracking control verbs are not available in the python re module.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You're right, I had it backwards. Editing now :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)

Code:

```
string = '<x:tagname x:attribute="value">test content with : symbols</x:tagname>'

stringx = string.replace(':', '--')

print(stringx)
```

Output:

```
<x--tagname x--attribute="value">test content with -- symbols</x--tagname>
```

Comment: This won't work because he needs to avoid editing outside of the tags.