# Unparseable XML input: Namespace type defined with different URIs: http://www.myCompany.com/HedgeAccounting and http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

In my legacy application we send xml message to one of the interfaces.
This XML has in its header this namespace (among few others)

```
xmlns:type="http://www.myCompany.com/HedgeAccounting
```

I would expect the Namespace to look like this

```
xmlns:HedgeAccounting="http://www.myCompany.com/HedgeAccounting
```

In a general way: what could be the reason for this difference ?

Comment: What exactly do you assume to be the difference? Both namespaces appear to be identical, only the assigned prefixes differ.

Comment: Maybe this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration) helps you.

Comment: When I change the generated namespace to xmlns:HedgeAccounting="http://www.myCompany.com/HedgeAccounting the Namespace type defined with different URIs error gone

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, `type` and `HedgeAccounting` are both *XML namespace **prefixes***.

XML namespace prefix names themselves are inconsequential.  It is only through their binding to an actual *XML namespace **URI*** that they derive meaning.  Use whatever conventions might apply, or make up your own.  You might use `ns1`, `x`, or `fred`, but as with any name, it's better to have some mnemonic justification.  For example, `xsd` and `xs` are often used for the XSD namespace.

### See also

- [What does the XML syntax with a colon mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38325104/290085)
- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)
- [Well-formed vs Valid XML: Namespace-well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)

Comment: When I change the generated namespace to xmlns:HedgeAccounting="myCompany.com/HedgeAccounting the Namespace type defined with different URIs error gone

Comment: Would have to see a  [mcve] to help you further, especially considering that your comment, question title, and question body appear to be inconsistently presenting whatever problem you're having.